# Delete a version of app in itunes connect

Tags: upload, version, app-store-connect

I have clicked New Version by mistake in my itunes connect app section.
I dont need it now and want to delete it. Its still not submitted for review. Is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

**No**, you can **not** remove it when it is in state `Waiting For Review` or `Upload Binary`.

**What you could do**
Upload a binary to the version and let them review, if you really have to delete it then you can now do that.

Hope that helps :)